# NDK installation is required for reuse NDK code?

Tags: java, android

I have downloaded code http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/downloads/detail?name=aacplayer-android-r25.zip&can=2&q= for playing  AAC file in ANDROID

and below is image of that code in eclipse

[image]

Here you can see that there is jni folder and libs folder in LIBS folder also contain .so files

Currently i have not installed any NDK and i have imported this project which is working fine...
but if i use this files and code into my project should i have to install NDK?

I have copy and paste this jni and libs folder to my application, now what should i have to do! How to tell my apps that this is the native code!

my apps folder structor is (after copy paste) below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to rebuild the .so files you should not need the NDK. Eclipse/Java/Android will handle them as fine as native java libraries. You need the ANdroid NDK if you want to be able to compile c/c++ code for the android platform.

Comment: Ok so if i copy and paste jni and libs folder will it work for me?

Comment: Yes. You might still need to tell eclipse to use them as Java native libraries.

Comment: No plaisthos if i copy and paste this code it is not running for me :(

Comment: Would u explain me how to tell eclipse to use them as Java Native Libraries?

Comment: You should post what error you are getting... "does not work is difficult to guess what your real problem is"

Comment: thes libs folder has to go directly under the root and not under res. You don't need the jni folder. Btw. there is still no real error message in your first post

Comment: hello plaishtos, thank you so much i have copied and pasted into root directory now error goes but how to tell apps that this is the native code which my apps have to use and how can i import this libs folder  into my project because here u can see that it's just copied and pasted not actually set into project path otherwise icon will be looking like uppar image